# React push objects within an array to useState array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem filling an array. Currently variable terapije contains an object within an array based on the if conditions (i've posted a few, but there's way more). I am using useState hook and i set the default value to an empty array which needs to be filled with terapije objects. Currently terapije is filled but my "terapijaForDropdown" is just an empty array. How can i push an existing array to another ? i've tried multiple solutions and nothing seems to work.

```
 function onSkupinaZdravilChange () {

        if (form.preparati){

            let skupine = form.preparati.map(p => p.preparati && +catalogue.preparat.display[p.preparati].skupinaZdravil.code)
            let terapije = []
            
            if (skupine.length === 1 && skupine.every(i => [1,2,3,4,5].includes(i))){
                terapije.push(findAttributeByCode(catalogue.terapija, '1'))
            }

            if (skupine.length === 2 && skupine.every(i => [1,2,3,4,5].includes(i))){
                terapije.push(findAttributeByCode(catalogue.terapija, '2'))
            }

            if (skupine.includes(6) || (skupine.length === 2 && skupine.includes(6) && skupine.every(i => [1,2,3,4,5].includes(i)))){
                terapije.push(findAttributeByCode(catalogue.terapija, '3'))
            }
                
            if (skupine.length === 1 && skupine.includes(6)){
                terapije.push(findAttributeByCode(catalogue.terapija, '4'))
            }

   setTerapijaForDropdown([...terapijaForDropdown, terapije]);

}}
```

```
const [terapijaForDropdown, setTerapijaForDropdown] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        onSkupinaZdravilChange();
     },[form.preparati])
```

Comment: how does the `terapijaForDropdown` state looks like? should this be an array or array of arrays? because doing `setTerapijaForDropdown([...terapijaForDropdown, terapije]);` will create array of arrays. are you suppose to destructure terapije too?  `setTerapijaForDropdown([...terapijaForDropdown, ...terapije]);`

Comment: @m5khan Thanks for the interest and potential answer, i've actually figured it out, I was console logging inside the function and the terapijaForDropdown only received an array once the function was completely finished, meaning outside the function the array was full as it should be. terapijaForDropdown was supposed to only return an array.

Comment: @Elrab If you've solved your problem, be sure to document your solution in an answer to this question and mark it as correct.  This is the way.

Comment: @PsiKai well the solution is pretty much the code i posted. It worked the entire time, i was just checking the output inside the function and there was none since the array was filled once the function was finished, meaning outside the function i got the correct values, i just didnt check there yet.

Comment: @Elrab That's fine.  Just remember the spirit of stack overflow is 10% answering _your_ question, and 90% answering future users who have the same question.